# Wikipedia api for image download fron json to c#

Tags: c#, json, image, download, wikipedia

I made an image class which I use to download image from wikipedia api. I make 3 function to show 3 images in 3 picturebox. I use "thumburl" image link from the json wiki api. Here is my image class code.

```
            class Images
            {

                public static PictureBox Image1 = new PictureBox();
                public static PictureBox Image2 = new PictureBox();
                public static PictureBox Image3 = new PictureBox();
                public static Label Image1_title = new Label();
                public static Label Image2_title = new Label();
                public static Label Image3_title = new Label();


                public static void Load_Image1(string name, string id,string LocationName)
                {


                    string Jpeg = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\C# tutorial Backup\Tourist_Place\Images\"+LocationName);

                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        var client = new WebClient();
                        var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=json&iiurlwidth=400&titles=" + name);
                        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
                        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);

                        string image1 = (string)obj["query"]["pages"][id]["imageinfo"][0]["thumburl"];
                        Image1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        Image1.LoadAsync(image1);

                        string image1_Title = (string)obj["query"]["pages"][id]["title"];
                        Image1_title.Text = image1_Title;

                        var hash = uri.GetHashCode();
                        var path = Path.Combine(Jpeg, hash.ToString("X") + ".jpg");
                        client.DownloadFile(image1, path);


                    }

                }

                public static void Load_Image2(string name, string id,string LocationName)
                {

                   string Jpeg = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\C# tutorial Backup\Tourist_Place\Images\" + LocationName);


                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        var client = new WebClient();
                        var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=json&iiurlwidth=400&titles=" + name);
                        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
                        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);


                        string image2 = (string)obj["query"]["pages"][id]["imageinfo"][0]["thumburl"];
                        Image2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        Image2.LoadAsync(image2);

                        string image2_Title = (string)obj["query"]["pages"][id]["title"];
                        Image2_title.Text = image2_Title;

                        var hash = uri.GetHashCode();
                        var path = Path.Combine(Jpeg, hash.ToString("X") + ".jpg");
                        client.DownloadFile(image2, path);
                    }

                }

                public static void Load_Image3(string name, string id, string LocationName)
                {

                    //string fileName = name + ".jpg";//plaese  change the storage location

                    string Jpeg = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\C# tutorial Backup\Tourist_Place\Images\"+ LocationName);
                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        var client = new WebClient();
                        var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=json&iiurlwidth=400&titles=" + name);
                        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
                        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);


                        string image3 = (string)obj["query"]["pages"][id]["imageinfo"][0]["thumburl"];
                        Image3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        Image3.LoadAsync(image3);//

                        string image3_Title = (string)obj["query"]["pages"][id]["title"];
                        Image3_title.Text = image3_Title;

                        var hash = uri.GetHashCode();
                        var path = Path.Combine(Jpeg, hash.ToString("X") + ".jpg");
                        client.DownloadFile(image3, path);
                    }

                }



            }


        }
```

Now in form.cs I call this class with function and put the value manually of all image, name and id. here is my form1.cs

```
      namespace Wikipedia_Image_Text_24_11_2015
     {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        POI_List.Combo_list = comboBox1;
        POI_List.List();


    }

     public void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


        Images.Image1 = pictureBox1;
        Images.Image2 = pictureBox2;
        Images.Image3 = pictureBox3;

        Images.Image1_title = label1;
        Images.Image2_title = label2;
        Images.Image3_title = label3;




        switch (comboBox1.Text)
        {

           case "Heidelberg Castle":

                Images.Load_Image1("File:Heidelberg-Schlo%C3%9F.JPG", "-1", "Heidelberg Castle");
                Images.Load_Image2("File:Heidelberg%2020060420%20021.jpg", "-1", "Heidelberg Castle");
                Images.Load_Image3("File:Rondell%20Heidelberger%20Schloss%20vom%20Stueckgarten.jpg", "-1", "Heidelberg Castle");


                break;


            case "Neuschwanstein Castle":
               Images.Load_Image1("File:Schloss%20Neuschwanstein%202013.jpg", "40677196", "Neuschwanstein Castle");
                Images.Load_Image2("File:Neuschwanstein%20castle.jpg", "-1", "Neuschwanstein Castle");
                Images.Load_Image3("File:Hohenschwangau_-_Schloss_Neuschwanstein5.jpg", "-1", "Neuschwanstein Castle");




                break;
```

I know there should be shorter way to make this coding easier.I tried a lot. but failed.It would be nice if someone answer me what should I do to make it more generic or dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to reduce the number of service call. As per Wikipedia [sandbox documentation][1]

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&titles=File%3ANeuschwanstein%20castle.jpg%7CFile%3AHohenschwangau_-_Schloss_Neuschwanstein5.jpg 
It accepts more than files(titles) within the request. So Just make one REST call. You will get array of pages. Parse it. Loop through the array and display the image. You don't need 3 separate method

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it and give my feedback as well.